# sorting an array that contains Methods by modifiers

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

DISCLAIMER: This is only part of a homework assignment I am currently doing

Say I have a method array which contains all of my declared methods

```
Method methodList[] = classGetter.getDeclaredMethods();
```

in which classGetter simply gets what class I want to get the methods of. Is there a way to sort this array by what kind of modifier is associated with the method? I see that when I print out the modifier using

```
for(Method m: methodList){
    System.out.println(m.getModifiers());
}
```

it returns integer values. I tried to sort using the Arrays.sort method but I got error exceptions. Any Pointers?

Comment: What would be the sort order? Can you give an example of wanted output? Like `public final` before `public`? Or do you want to just sort on what returns `getModifiers`?

Comment: essentially what the assignment wants us to do is to take in the methods and print out various information about the method using reflection. However, we need to get the non static methods first, and then the static methods. So essentially, anything static should be printed out last. I have everything else working, only thing is that the print comes out the same order the methods are declared in my class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Method`s are not `Comparable`, you have to specify a `Comparator` determining the order, e.g.:

```
Arrays.sort(methodList, Comparator.comparingInt(Method::getModifiers));
```

you may apply a mask to remove those bits that are irrelevant to your desired ordering, e.g.:

```
Arrays.sort(methodList, Comparator.comparingInt(
    m -> m.getModifiers()&(Modifier.PUBLIC|Modifier.PRIVATE|Modifier.PROTECTED)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it works. It was just to separate the static and non static functions. I appreciate it and +1 for the reason as to why it would not work the regular way if to sort the method array